# Generate a URL programmatically using the route information without the request context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

I'd like to include a relative URL as parameter in one of my custom validation attributes. Something like:

```
[RemoteValidation(Url= Html.ActionLink("Index","Home"))]
public class Lalala...
```

How can I do it?

I know that usually I need the request context in order to generate an URL, but considering it is just a relative one, is there any way I can generate the relative url for an action and controller names?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? there can be alternate ways.

Comment: I'd like to create a validator that I can use for remote validations. For example, a validator that tell if a username is already registered from the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the [`[Remote]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute.aspx) attribute instead of writing custom attributes?

```
[Remote("Index", "Home")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

And here's a [nice article](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=198) illustrating it in action.

Comment: Wow! that's nice. How is possible that attribute doesn't appear in this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx?

Comment: @vtortola, because it is not defined in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assembly but in the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly.

Comment: Anyway I'm still interested in how RemoteAttribute does it.

Comment: @vtorola, it does it by implementing the [`IClientValidatable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable.aspx) interface and the `GetValidationRules` method where you have access to the HttpContext and can build urls. You can simply download the source code of ASP.NET MVC 3 and take a look at the implementation. It's pretty trivial.

Comment: Thanks! do you know where may I find a list of all validation attributes built-in in MVC3 ? Thanks a million again.

Comment: @vtortola, no I don't know where you can get this full list from.